# Write driver for laptop sensor

Tags: linux, driver, sensors

I want to write a driver for sensor which can tell me if my yoga 2 pro is in tablet mode or not.

I read some about writting modules but as far as I know, I need to know address in memory which belongs to this device (hope it's correct), and here is my question.

How can I find information about this address?

Or what should I do to find this address?

Comment: Have you checked if there isn't already a sensor using a known driver?

Answer (score 1):

Both in Windows and in Android you absolutely don't need to write a driver for this purpose. To identify Tablet/Laptop mode, you need just one sensor - accelerometer. In Windows 8.1 + this functionality is built-in,  but in case you wish to build your own application you can use an example from here: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Accelerometer-Sensor-Sample-22982671

In Android, you have a Java API to all sensors:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html

However if you have a custom Linux installed on your Yoga, there indeed may arise a need to add a driver. As of now, the most useful solution are IIO drivers that are part of Kernel:
http://events.linuxfoundation.org/sites/events/files/slides/lceu15_baluta.pdf
 If there aren't already there, you'll have to rebuild a Kernel and include those drivers. If you don't know how to find a device address, you have to learn for a while about Linux Kernel in general. Anyway, some tips:

- Sensors are normally defined via USB/HID interface
- If you still have your Windows along with Linux, you may go to
  Devices Manager and there you can easily reach Sensors and see what
  address is used by a driver.